# Удвоение "н" в "образованный"

Tags: удвоенные-согласные

Почему в слове "образованный" имеет место удвоение "н"? По какой причине я должен полагать, что это слово произошло от существительного "образование", а не от глагола "образовать"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это слово имеет два значения:

> ОБРАЗ'ОВАННЫЙ , образованная, образованное. 1. ( •кратк. образован,
>   образована, образовано). **прич. страд. прош. вр. от образовать** . "Мы
>   пошли на вал, возвышение, образованное природой и укрепленное
>   частоколом." Пушкин.
>
> 2.( •кратк. образован, образованна,
>   образованно). **Получивший образование, обладающий широким образованием**,
>   просвещенный, культурный. Нельзя быть образованным человеком, если не
>   знать основ марксизма-ленинизма. Она очень образованна. | То же в
>   знач. сущ. "Образованные одолели: из чиновников, из офицеров, из
>   университетов - всё на сцену лезут." А.Островский.

http://www.onlinedics.ru/slovar/ushakov/t/obrazovannyj.html

А теперь о правописании "нн" в прилагательных и причастиях, произошедших от глаголов.

Итак, 2 буквы «н» следует писать, если:

1.Имена прилагательные и причастия образованы от глаголов совершенного вида (если есть приставка, кроме НЕ, то вид будет точно совершенный: связанный, скошенный, нескошенный, но некошеный). Запомнить: раненый.

2.**Если имеются такие суффиксы, как -ева- или -ова-**, например: организованная экскурсия, выкорчеванный лес и пр.). Исключения: жеваный и кованый (ов- и ев- входят в корень, а не являются суффиксами).

3.Если в предложении имеется какое-либо зависимое слово (например, плетенная из прутьев). https://fb.ru/article/148093/pravopisanie-n-i-nn-v-prilagatelnyih-suffiksyi-prilagatelnyih-pravila-isklyucheniya

**Так что *образованное природой* - причастие, -НН- пишется, потому что есть суффикс -ОВА-, сов.вид.**

**Образованный человек - прилагательное от сущ. образование** (человек, получивший образование), но восходит оно тоже к глаголу образовать, так что вполне можно сказать, что это отглагольное прилагательное и -НН- пишется по этой же причине - есть суфф.-ОВА-.